# .js file is not loaded on firefox and internet explorer - works in chrome though

Tags: javascript

I have a .js file containing generic functions which are used throughout application. After some recent changes, the file is
- Completely loaded and works properly on Chrome
- Throws syntax error and is incompletely loaded on firefox.
- Not loaded in internet explorer 8 at all.

Any idea what could be the reason behind?

Comment: My question is very generic. Have double checked file for syntax errors and special symbols. none found.
I would just like to know is there any difference between browser interpretations for .js files included in html pages?

Comment: Please provide more information about what the error was, and post the code you think caused the problem. Without something to work with, it is unlikely someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Found the problem. Load balancer was dropping packets :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it works in chrome and not firefox then the first check I would make is in my javascript array calls to ensure that I'm using [ and ] in stead of ( and )

Comment: Yup. [ and ] used everywhere for array calls.

Comment: Back to the drawing board then. Would you mind showing me the code? It might help. I understand if you don't want people to copy your methods, but any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: These 2 were the last edits on file:

function StopBubbling(event) {
    if (event.stopPropagation) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    else if(window.event){
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
     }
}



function Display_Toggle(id) {
    var element;
    element = $('#' + id);

    if (!($(element).css('display') == 'none')) {
        $(element).hide();
    } else {
        $(element).show();
    }
}